# Where is the 'Recent Items' block in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I have CiviCRM 5.33.2 on Drupal 8.9.12.

On Drupal 7, CiviCRM created a number of Drupal Blocks that could be displayed according to the Theme configuration, including the very useful 'Recent Items'.

On Drupal 8 I am not seeing any of these Blocks at all.  Where are they?

Comment: Did you know there is also a recent items extension for CiviCRM that will place a recent items menu item in the CiviCRM menu? That is  the one I always use now.

Answer (score 2):

Oops.

I have just found out how to insert a Block in D8 - you have to click a button to get the list, rather than scrolling down as on D7.  The CiviCRM stuff is there OK.

Comment: Yes the redesigned block screen confused me for a while at first. I'd also suggest, since sidebars seem to be going out of style and civi looks a bit messed up in bartik, to look at the [recent items](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.recentmenu) extension which makes it a menu dropdown instead. That's what I've been using. Ignore the KAM requirement that's not needed anymore.